# hbase or text files as input to Map Reduce

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

I would like to know which configuration will be faster. Well i have the option to have as input to the Map Reduce several text files to process or the option of get the input from HBase.

For my purpose i need to read all the available data.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text files are stored in HDFS then reading data from there will be faster than HBase. The reason behind this is that when you read data form HBase it does a lot more than HDFS, like reading the KeyValues, returning the most current row or specified timestamps etc. On the other hand when you read data from HDFS, it's just a matter of opening a reader on that file and start reading it sequentially. There is no jumping from one place to another which causes the delay in reading(this jumping is the thing which allows HBase to provide you random read/write access). This is the reason HBase is a few times slower than HDFS in this processing context.

But this holds good  in a batch context (e.g., as a MapReduce source or sink). When you need low latency access to small amounts of data from within a large data set then HBase is the preferable choice.

Hope this answers the question.

Comment: My knowledge regarding hadoop, is that files are stored in chunks (HDFS) and these chunks are broken to set of lines which are provided to the n mappers to do the job! So i think so that it must be faster using text files rather than querying HBase to retrieve in fact all the available data. 

I agree with your answer. It should be faster.

Comment: There seems to be a bit of confusion. The HDFS chucks which you have mentioned(called as blocks) are different from the chunks which go to the mappers(called as InputSplits). While blocks are physical division of the data, InpUtSplits are just logical splits which are created based on the InputFormat you are using.

Comment: Yeah i totally agree with you Tariq, i may haven't clear enough. I m not an experienced hadoop user. InputSplit by default returns line by line the content of the logical splits isn't it?

Comment: Not a problem :)..Correct. But this is the behavior of TextInputFormat..If you use some other InputFormat the criteria behind split creation might differ. For example DBInputFormat.

Comment: You are welcome :)..You might wanna accept/upvote the answer if you think it answers your query.